# How to redirect Remote resource to local?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is a react application created by Umijs.

When I request `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple@14.0.0/img/apple/sheets-256/64.png` I wish it can be redirect to `localhost:8080/64.png`.Because the remote resource sometime is slowly.

And then,It was requested by **Third-party library**.So I'cant use `request Interceptor`

How to redirect Remote resource to local?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXoZH.png)

It was requested by **Third-party library**.So I'cant use `request Interceptor`

Comment: That only works if the user's computer happens to be running a web server on port 8000, which isn't going to be true for most people.

Comment: There are some ways, your question is too board to answer.